# Make (map f c1 c2) map (count c1) times, even if c2 has less elements

Tags: clojure

When doing

```
(map f [0 1 2] [:0 :1])
```

`f` will get called twice, with the arguments being

- 0 :0
- 1 :1

Is there a simple yet efficient way, i.e. without producing more intermediate sequences etc., to make `f` get called for every value of the first collection, with the following arguments?

- 0 :0
- 1 :1
- 2 nil

**Edit** Addressing question by @fl00r in the comments.

The actual use case that triggered this question needed map to always work exactly `(count first-coll)` times, regardless if the second (or third, or ...) collection was longer.

It's a bit late in the game now and somewhat unfair after having accepted an answer, but if a good answer gets added that only does what I specifically asked for - mapping `(count first-coll)` times - I would accept that.

Comment: What should `(map f [0 1] [:0 :1 :2])` return?

Answer (score 5):

You could do:

```
(map f [0 1 2] (concat [:0 :1] (repeat nil)))
```

Basically, pad the second coll with an infinite sequence of nils. `map` stops when it reaches the end of the first collection.

An (eager) loop/recur form that walks to end of longest:

```
(loop [c1 [0 1 2] c2 [:0 :1] o []]
  (if (or (seq c1) (seq c2))                
    (recur (rest c1) (rest c2) (conj o (f (first c1) (first c2))))
    o))
```

Or you could write a lazy version of map that did something similar.

Comment: Love this `concat` approach

Comment: @eugene-beresovsky Is there something lacking from this answer? I would like to contribute an answer but I don't see any unaddressed concerns.

Answer (score 1):

A general lazy version, as suggested by [Alex Miller's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41929488/1562315), is

```
(defn map-all [f & colls]
  (lazy-seq
    (when-not (not-any? seq colls)
      (cons
        (apply f (map first colls))
        (apply map-all f (map rest colls))))))
```

For example,

```
(map-all vector [0 1 2] [:0 :1])
;([0 :0] [1 :1] [2 nil])
```

You would probably want to specialise `map-all` for one and two collections.

Comment: I accept this as the answer, as it is easy to use, and `map-all` does not create any intermediate sequences, compared to `map` - and arity overloads for one, two, and three collections can be added, just as done by `map`.

Comment: @EugeneBeresovsky I've found that writing reference versions - clear but possibly slow - of core functions is the best ways to truly understand them. This is just another such.

Comment: I would advise against doing it this way. This implementation throws a Stackoverflow: `(doall (map-all (constantly 8) (repeat 5000 8) (repeat 5000 8)))`

Answer (score 0):

**just for fun**

this could easily be done with common lisp's `do` macro. We could implement it in clojure and do this (and much more fun things) with it:

```
(defmacro cl-do [clauses [end-check result] & body]
  (let [clauses (map #(if (coll? %) % (list %)) clauses)
        bindings (mapcat (juxt first second) clauses)
        nexts (map #(nth % 2 (first %)) clauses)]
    `(loop [~@bindings]
       (if ~end-check
         ~result
         (do
           ~@body
           (recur ~@nexts))))))
```

and then just use it for mapping (notice it can operate on more than 2 colls):

```
(defn map-all [f & colls]
  (cl-do ((colls colls (map next colls))
          (res [] (conj res (apply f (map first colls)))))
         ((every? empty? colls) res)))
```

in repl:

```
user> (map-all vector [1 2 3] [:a :s] '[z x c v])
;;=> [[1 :a z] [2 :s x] [3 nil c] [nil nil v]]
```